# cannot GET /myNodeApp with docker + traefik + nodejs stack

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, traefik

I am trying to do the following:

- Publicly run a dockerized nodejs app
- Use traefik as a reverse proxy for HTTPS

My file structure is:

```
root/
 |_ docker-compose.yml
 |_www/
    |_ app/
        |_ Dockerfile
        |_ package.json
        |_ server.js
        |_ static/
```

my `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    myNodeApp:
      container_name: myNodeApp
      build:
          context: ./www/app
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=production
      networks:
        - default
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myNodeApp.rule=Host(`my.url.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/myNodeApp`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myNodeApp.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
        - traefik.docker.network=myExternalNetworkName
      volumes:
        - /home/myUsername/myProjectDir/www/app:/var/www/html
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myExternalNetworkName
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /home/myUsername/myProjectDir/www/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

When I write `$ docker-compose up`, I get:

```
Attaching to myProjectDir_1
myNodeApp_1  | serving on port:  3000
myNodeApp_1  | base dir:  /usr/src/app
myNodeApp_1  | dist folder:  /usr/src/app/dist
```

and when I go to `https://my.url.example.com/myNodeApp`, I get:

```
cannot GET /myNodeApp
```

Now I suspect this may have something to do with the fact that the logs show that it is using `/usr/src/app` as the base dir (and `/usr/src/app/dist` as the dist folder). But I never specified this. When I view those folders on my local machine they don't exist.

Any ideas as to how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the location of you `Dockerfile`

Modify your `docker-compose.yml` with

```
services:
    myNodeApp:
      container_name: myNodeApp
      build:
          context: ./www/app
```

remove the image

```
image: node:14
```

[Further reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build)

Comment: sadly I still get the same error, I'll update my code with this modification though

Comment: what is `docker-compose up` log now?

Comment: It is the same output:
`serving on port: 3000`; `base dir: /usr/src/app/`; `dist folder: /usr/src/app/dist`

Comment: use `docker-compose up --remove-orphans --build`

Comment: oooh this is progress! The output is now:
`serving on port: 3000`; `base dir: /home/myUsername/myProjectDir/www/app`; `dist folder: /home/myUsername/myProjectDir/www/app/dist`. This seems to actually reflect my file structure. Sadly I still get cannot GET

Comment: I'm wondering if this is maybe a problem with my node.js server too? Initially I have it hosting the main page at `localhost:3000`, so it would try to GET `/`, but with Traefik I am making it look for `/myNodeApp`